# after inserting into History table how i need to update again

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Transaction table and Transaction History table. I have written Update Trigger it will maintain updated record in history table and it will not allow Duplication but how can update ISActive column when ever it updated status to Y or N .Record is maintaining but how can i update changes made to the same record without Duplication

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Transaction] 
     ON [dbo].[Transaction_Details]
     FOR UPDATE 
     AS

     Declare @ApplicationNo varchar(20);
     Declare @PaymentID varchar(20);
      Declare @CreatedBy varchar(20)
     DECLARE @CreatedDate DATETIME ;
     DECLARE @UpdatedDate DATETIME ;
     DECLARE @UpdatedBy VARCHAR(20) ;
     DECLARE @IsActive CHAR(2)

     Select @ApplicationNo = I.ApplicationNo from INSERTED I
     Select @PaymentID = I.PaymentID from INSERTED I
     Select @CreatedDate = CAST(I.CreatedDate AS DATETIME) from INSERTED I
     Select @UpdatedDate = CAST(I.UpdatedDate  AS DATETIME)from INSERTED I
     Select @UpdatedBy = I.UpdatedBy from INSERTED I
     Select @IsActive = I.IsActive from INSERTED I

     INSERT INTO [BPS].[dbo].[Transaction_Details_History]
           ([ApplicationNo]
           ,[PaymentID]
           ,[CreatedBy]
           ,[UpdatedDate]
           ,[UpdatedBy]
           ,[IsActive])

          SELECT @ApplicationNo,
                 @PaymentID, 
                 @CreatedBy,
                 @UpdatedDate,
                 @UpdatedBy,
                 @IsActive
                    FROM INSERTED I
           WHERE NOT EXISTS 
           (SELECT 
                [ApplicationNo]
           ,[PaymentID]
           ,[CreatedBy]
           ,[UpdatedDate]
           ,[UpdatedBy]
           ,[IsActive] 

                     FROM [Transaction_Details_History]
           WHERE @ApplicationNo = [ApplicationNo] 
)
GO
```

Comment: Your logic is not clear, but what is clear is that your trigger is not written properly, it is only designed to work for updating a single row, whereas in reality the memory resident table `inserted` can contain multiple rows. What do you mean by *"how can i update changes made to the same record without Duplication"*?

Comment: You might want to look at the `merge` statement.

Comment: yeah when i update on Transaction table record will insert into history table again if i do update on Transaction table then updation should happen on History table with out inserting same record

Comment: yeah we can handle this in MERGE statement but in MERGE in trigger HOW??

Comment: @GarethD yeah it will insert into History table but will not allow duplication of same record but if i do any update on Transaction table then for the same record in history updated changes should be reflected if my approach is wrong then suggest me the correct way so i can achieve desired result set

Comment: And what is the desired resultset?   Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), you simply check to see if a record exists, if it does update it, if not insert it

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Transaction] 
ON [dbo].[Transaction_Details]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN

MERGE dbo.Transaction_Details_History AS h
USING inserted AS i
    ON i.ApplicationNo = h.ApplicationNo
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET PaymentID = i.PaymentID,
        CreatedBy = i.CreatedBy,
        UpdatedDate = i.UpdatedDate,
        UpdatedBy = i.UpdatedDate,
        IsActive = i.IsActive
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (ApplicationNo, PaymentID, CreatedBy, UpdatedDate, UpdatedBy, IsActive)
    VALUES (i.ApplicationNo, i.PaymentID, i.CreatedBy, i.UpdatedDate, i.UpdatedBy, i.IsActive)

END
GO
```

If you only want to update the history record if `IsActive` changes, then you can add a condition to the `MATCHED` clause:

```
MERGE dbo.Transaction_Details_History AS h
USING inserted AS i
    ON i.ApplicationNo = h.ApplicationNo
WHEN MATCHED AND i.IsActive <> h.IsActive THEN UPDATE
    SET PaymentID = i.PaymentID,
        CreatedBy = i.CreatedBy,
        UpdatedDate = i.UpdatedDate,
        UpdatedBy = i.UpdatedDate,
        IsActive = i.IsActive
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (ApplicationNo, PaymentID, CreatedBy, UpdatedDate, UpdatedBy, IsActive)
    VALUES (i.ApplicationNo, i.PaymentID, i.CreatedBy, i.UpdatedDate, i.UpdatedBy, i.IsActive)
```